# Sending mails in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, smtp, sendmail

I have used 'smtp_tls' gem in ruby 1.8.6 and used smtp_settings for sending mail using 'gmail.com' as domain. Now i have to use the same functionality in ruby 1.8.7 and i don't know which gem to use and how to use.

I have tried 'action_mailer_tls' gem too.

Please tell me the gem for mail notification and method for how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: You dont need a gem for that in ruby 1.8.7 and up, they have built in support for smtp+tls. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base#579-Using-gmail-SMTP-server-to-send-mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my 1.8.7 ruby project (rails 2.3.5) I have this line in enviroment (because if you want to use gmail, in rails 2.3.x, to send your notification you need to install action_mailer_tls. In rails 3 you don't have to do this because tls is used by default)

```
config.gem 'action_mailer_tls', :lib => 'smtp_tls.rb'
```

and in config/initializers/smtp_gmail.rb you can use following setting:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :user_name            => "your_email_adress@gmail.com",
  :password             => "your_password"
```

}

Comment: thanks a lot..i have implemented it and your code is also working